# Flask app.before_request is not working when it moved to other module

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning Flask these days.

At first, I wrote whole codes in `main.py`, and started to split codes as code increase.

Everything was OK. But `@app.before_request` worked well when it in `main.py`, but stopped working after move this code into a separate module.

I spent many hours to catch the reason, but even imagined yet. :(

`main.py` is here

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(settings)
db = SQLAlchemy()


@app.before_request
def working():
    from user.models import User
    print '### called in main ###'
    g.user = User.get_by_session()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.init_app(app)
    app.register_blueprint(frontend.views.blueprint)
    app.register_blueprint(user.views.blueprint)
    import frontend.helpers
    app.run()
```

and `frontend/helpers.py`

```
from flask import g
from main import app
from user.models import User

@app.before_request
def not_working():
    print '### called in frontend.helpers ###'
    g.user = User.get_by_session()
```

The result shows that `@app.before_request` in `frontend/helpers.py` not called.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2015 15:55:35] "GET /login HTTP/1.1" 200 -
### called in main ###
```

How can I do this to work well?

Comment: How is `app` imported in `frontend/helpers.py`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Hi, I wrote it into article

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are running `main.py` as the main entry script from the command line, then the whole namespace of the module is stored in the `__main__` module, not the `main` module. This is also why the `if __name__ == '__main__'` test succeeds.

However, your `frontend/helpers.py` module imports from `main`, which as far as Python is concerned, a *different module*. You now created *two distinct `Flask` instances*, each living in a different module namespace.

In other words, `__main__.app` is being used to run your Flask server, but your `before_request` hook is registered with a *different, separate* `main.app` object.

Don't use the same module to run as a script and to create the `Flask` WSGI object. Use a *separate* module for this. Don't try to use `from __main__ import app` as that'll break when you deploy as to a WSGI container like `gunicorn` or `mod_wsgi`.

Comment: Knowing the situation, it became easier. I set `frontend.helpers` as blueprint, and used `@blueprint.before_app_request` instead of `@app.before_request`. Thank you.